# Изменить содержимое балуна при клике на радио-кнопку

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать так, чтобы при клике на полигон (одна из зон доставки), в балуне была разная информация в соответствии с выбранной радио-кнопкой. Т.е. если выбран 0.5 в балуне была одна информация, а при переключений радио-кнопки другая информация. Также подскажите как это завязать с конкретными полигонами (2 шт. для примера).

сейчас содержимое балуна устанавливается на 49 строке:

```
obj.properties.set('balloonContentHeader', 'Стоимость доставки: ' + obj.properties.get('price') + ' р.');
```

ссылка на демку https://jsfiddle.net/Legioner56/t78bs4wa/21/

Comment: А что не получается? Ну то есть концепт простой, в момент формирования данных для балуна проверить какая радио-кнопка выбрана и создать контент для балуна в зависимости от этого. Если нужна обратная взаимосвязь, то в момент выбора радиокнопки поменять контент у балуна.

Comment: как сделать в момент загрузки понятно, а вот как получить обратную взаимосвязь уже после инициализации, уже проблема

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт об изменении содержимого балуна при смене радиокнопки, вам достаточно просто добавить действия в ваш event **checkState()** и менять содержимое балуна посредством [**setData()**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/IPopupManager.html#method_detail__setData).

Если при этом нужно возвращать первозданный вид балуна при смене чекбокса, нужно предварительно сохранять его в переменную через [**getData()**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/IPopupManager.html#method_detail__getData).

Функцию в вашем коде тогда можно изменить так:

```
var realBalloon;
function checkState() {
    if ($('#delZone').prop('checked')) {
        console.log(realBalloon)
        if (realBalloon !== null) {
            myMap.balloon.setData({
                properties: realBalloon.properties
            })
        }
        deliveryZones.setOptions('fillOpacity', 0.4);
        deliveryZones.setOptions('outline', true);
    } else {
        deliveryZones.setOptions('fillOpacity', 0);
        deliveryZones.setOptions('outline', false);
        realBalloon = myMap.balloon.getData()
            myMap.balloon.setData({
                properties: {
                    balloonContent: "Test"
                }
            })
    }
}
```